# Output a radio button in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button, output

I'm trying to input the value of the checked radio button as one of a functions parameres (here *sign*). This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="proj4js/lib/proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


    <script>
    function func1 (x,y, sign){

         var z=(x+y)*sign
         document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;

        }                           

    </script>
    <form >
    first input:<br>
    <input id="Y" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
    <br>
    second input:<br>
    <input id="X" type="text" x="X" value=15>
    <br> 
  <input type="radio" name="hem" value=1 id = "N" >north
  <input type="radio" name="hem" value=-1 id = "S" >south
    The Answer:<br>
    <input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 

    <br><br>
    </form>


<button type="button" onclick="func1(Number(document.getElementById('X').value),Number(document.getElementById('Y').value), ?? )"> try it </button>
```

I don't know what to put instead of **??** ? The *sign* determines if sign is positive or negative.

Comment: plz explain what is the use of  sign  parameter.. why you r mulltiplying it.. is it simple addition of two inputs..?

Comment: "The sign determines if sign is positive or negative.". It detemines if WHAT is positive or negative?

Comment: the z value. it is either +1 or -1 and is multiplied by sign value

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("Z").value = z;` instead of `document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;`  when you  are trying to show answer in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

make input elements as

```
<form id="demoForm">
    first input:<br>
    <input id="Y" type="text" value=85>
    <br>
    second input:<br>
    <input id="X" type="text" value=15>
    <input type="radio" name="hem" value="1"  id="N" >north
    <input type="radio" name="hem" value="-1" id ="S" >south
    The Answer:<br>
    <input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 
    </form>
<script>
function getRadioVal(form, name) {
    var val;
    // get list of radio buttons with specified name
    var radios = form.elements[name];

    // loop through list of radio buttons
    for (var i=0, len=radios.length; i<len; i++) {
        if ( radios[i].checked ) { // radio checked?
            val = radios[i].value; // if so, hold its value in val
            break; // and break out of for loop
        }
    }
    return val; // return value of checked radio or undefined if none checked
}

var val = getRadioVal( document.getElementById('demoForm'), 'hem' );
alert(val); //you can pass this value as parameter
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to write a helper function to collect your paramters and then call your function from this function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--
<script src="proj4js/lib/proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
-->
</head>
<body>



<form >
first input:<br>
<input id="Y" type="text" y="Y" value=85>
<br>
second input:<br>
<input id="X" type="text" x="X" value=15>
<br> 
 <input type="radio" name="hem" value="1" id="N" >north</input>
 <input type="radio" name="hem" value="-1" id="S" >south </input>
The Answer:<br>
<input id="Z" type="text" z="Z" > 

<br><br>
</form>


<button type="button"     onclick="func1(Number(document.getElementById('X').value),Number(document.getElementById('Y').value), getAppropriateValue() )"> try it </button>

<script>
function func1 (x,y, sign){
     var z=(x+y)*sign
     document.getElementById("Z").value = z;
    }

function getAppropriateValue(){

    var result = 0;
    var checkboxN = document.getElementById('N');
    var checkboxS = document.getElementById('S');
    if(checkboxN && checkboxN.checked) result = 1;
    if(checkboxS && checkboxS.checked) result = -1;
    return result;
}

</script>
```

Comment: 1. id = "N" => id="N", id = "S" change to id="N"
2. Put all the scripts after the html portion so the script can access elements by their ids
3. Create a separate function which would compute value depending on the radios property "checked"
4. Insert that function instead of ??
5. I didn't modify your code much, but it would be better to add event listener to the button instead of using html "onclick" attribute

Comment: also write document.getElementById("Z").value = z; instead of document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to get the value of the checked

```
 $('input[name=hem]:checked').val()
```

Just need to make sure that the form you're using has an id. Then you wouldn't have to pass to the function just get the value directly from the form in your function.

```
<script>
function func1 (x,y){
     var sign = $('input[name=hem]:checked').val();
     var z=(x+y)*sign;
     document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;

    }                           

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can entirely take off third param and can output sign based on radio checked property.

```
<script>
function func1 (x,y) {
    var z=(x+y);
    if(document.getElementById("N").checked) {  
          z= z*1;
      }elseif(document.getElementById("N").checked) {
          z=z*-1;
      }
     document.getElementById("Z").value = z;
}
</script>
```